# Completely auto DB upgradable Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I am trying to use flyway for DB migrations and Spring boot's flyway support for auto-upgrading DB upon application start-up and subsequently this database will be used by my JPA layer

However this requires that schema be present in the DB so that primary datasource initialization is successful. What are the options available to run a SQL script that will create the required schema before flyway migrations happen.

Note that If I use flyway gradle plugin (and give the URL as `jdbc:mysql://localhost/mysql`. It does create the schema for me. Am wondering if I could make this happen from Java code on application startup.

Comment: Have you gone into [this part](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-execute-flyway-database-migrations-on-startup) of the documentation?

Comment: yes. And I guess my question still stands. I will like to know means to create schema and then do flyway migrations upon application startup.

Comment: Haven't used flyway by myself, but, doesn't a migration create the schema itself when empty database found? Anyway, from the documentation I have posted, you've got the Spring Batch choice too, which does exactly what you want (execute an SQL script when initializing). It would be good to have flyway doing everything, though. Can you edit your question with the configuration you're going with right now?

Answer (score 0):

Flyway does not support full installation when schema is empty, just migration-by-migration execution.
You could though add schema/user creation scripts in the first migration, though then your migration scripts need to be executed with sysdba/root/admin user and you need to set current schema at the beginning of each migration.

If using Flyway, the least problematic way is to install schema for the first time manually and do a baseline Flyway task (also manually). Then you are ready for next migrations to be done automatically.

Although Flyway is a great tool for database migrations it does not cover this particular use case well (installing schema for the first time).

Answer (score 0):

"Am wondering if I could make this happen from Java code on application startup."

The simple answer is yes as Flyway supports programmatic configuration from with java applications. The starting point in the flyway documentation can be found here

```
 https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/
```

flyway works with a standard JDBC DataSource and so you can code the database creation process in Java and then have flyway handle the schema management. In many environment you are likely to require 2 steps anyway as the database/schema creation will need admin rights to the database, while the ongoing schema management will need an account with reduced access rights.

Answer (score 0):

- what you need is to implement the interface [FlywayCallback](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/javadoc/org/flywaydb/core/api/callback/FlywayCallback.html)
- in order to kick start the migration manually from you code you can use the migrate() method on the [flyway class](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/javadoc/org/flywaydb/core/Flyway)
- tracking the migration process can be done through the MigrationInfoService() method of the flyway class

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if your app has a single datasource that expects the schema to exist, Flyway will not be able to use that datasource to create the scheme.  You must create another datasource that is not bound to the schema and use the unbounded datasource by way of a [FlywayMigrationStrategy](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayMigrationStrategy.java).

In your properties file:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myschema
  bootstrapDatasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
```

In your config file:

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
public DataSourceProperties primaryDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return primaryDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.bootstrapDatasource")
public DataSource bootstrapDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

And in your FlywayMigrationStrategy file:

```
@Inject
@Qualifier("bootstrapDataSource")
public void setBootstrapDataSource(DataSource bootstrapDataSource) {
    this.bootstrapDataSource = bootstrapDataSource;
}

@Override
public void migrate(Flyway flyway) {
    flyway.setDataSource(bootstrapDataSource);
    ...
    flyway.migrate()
}
```